# NodeJS Child Process reference to main process

Tags: node.js, process, signals, child-process

I'm trying to wrap my head around creating separate processes in NodeJS.

If I was to fork a child process and send it an object would that object be passed in by reference? So if I was to edit a variable within the child process on that object it would change on the main process too? Or is it the only way to do something like this is to send a message to the main process telling it what to change the variable to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js docs clearly say that:

> It is important to keep in mind that spawned Node.js child processes
>   are independent of the parent with exception of the IPC communication
>   channel that is established between the two. Each process has its own
>   memory, with their own V8 instances.

But there is a concept of Shared Memory in Linux. Here is a library called ['EMS.js'](http://synsem.com/EMS.js/) that allows to use it in Node.js.

Here is an example. I set numbers in child and parent and then read them correspondingly.

master.js:

```js
const {fork} = require('child_process');
const ems = require('ems')(1);
const _ = require('lodash');

const shared = ems.new({
 filename: '/tmp/shared.ems',
 heapSize: 10000,
 dimensions: 100,
 useMap: true,
    //Notice this option here
 useExisting: false,
 ES6proxies: true
});

setInterval(function () {
 shared.parentProperty = `Parent sets: ${_.random(1, 100)}`;
 console.log(shared.childProperty);
}, 500);

//I inherit stdio here to see the output of both processes in console
let child1 = fork('./slave-1.js', {stdio: 'inherit'});
```

slave-1.js:

```js
const _ = require('lodash');

console.log('Slave started');

const ems = require('ems')(1);
const shared = ems.new({
 filename: '/tmp/shared.ems',
 dimensions: 100,
 useMap: true,
 useExisting: true,
 ES6proxies: true
});

setInterval(function () {
 console.log(shared.parentProperty);
 shared.childProperty = `Child sets: ${_.random(1, 100)}`;
}, 500);
```

Also check out [the docs](http://syntheticsemantics.com/EMS.js/reference.html) as there is a lot options + a lot of stuff like barriers etc. Plus be careful with the heap size and dimensions options not to run out of memory.

The output:

```
Slave started
undefined
Parent sets: 52
Child sets: 52
...
```